# Python global variables : too global for me

Tags: python, variables, scope

Below, I would like the `s` var be global to the `f` function, but local to the `principal` function.

It seems `global` means "The Most Global in the Module".
How can I make one less global scope ?

```
s="what the hell"
print(s)

def principal():
    s ="hey"
    def f():
        global s 
        if len(s) < 8:
            s += " !"
            f()

    f()
    return s
print(principal())

what the hell
hey
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you are going for, since `global` has an unambiguous meaning in Python. If you want to modify the variable `s` as defined in `principal()` within `f()` you can use `nonlocal`:

```py
s="what the hell"
print(s)

def principal():
    s = "hey"
    def f():
        nonlocal s 
        if len(s) < 8:
            s += " !"
            f()

    f()
    return s
print(principal())
```

But the real goal here would probably be, to avoid constructs like that altogether and pass the respective variables as arguments and return the modified values from (pure) functions.

Comment: Oh I didn't know `nonlocal`